# Is it possible that the Gaussian Elimination process will never stop if we run into a loop?

Tags: linear-algebra

My thoughts is a no. Gaussian elimination will always stop no matter what, especially when we get a pivot or simplify till the satisfied equation.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop"?

Comment: loop refers to a non-stop process. Is a term used in computing.

Comment: Yes, I know English. I don't understand how you suggest this should apply here.

Comment: This might be a better question on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

No, the Gaussian elimination algorithm cannot loop if performed correctly.

When you reach the $m$th row you may need to swap it with a lower row to get a non-zero coefficient in the column $m$ of the $m$th row. You then add (or subtract) multiples of the $m$th row to the rows below it so that the coefficient in column $m$ of each of these lower rows becomes $0$. If there are $n$ rows in the matrix then this requires at most $n-m+1$ row operations (and perhaps fewer).

The whole algorithm therefore takes at most

$\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} (n-m+1) = \sum_{k=2}^{n} k = \frac{n^2+n-2} 2$

row operations.

Comment: Where can I find the formula. I like your explaination.

Comment: @user4622 There is an article on the Gaussian elimination algorithm on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination